# INPUT a List to stored procedure

Tags: sql, hana

I get a list of elments from R and I have to obtain the records from database that belong to a the list of elements.

INPUT:

```
'12345','23456', '34567', '45678'
```

PROCEDURE:

```
   CREATE PROCEDURE "SCHEMA"."GET_RECORDS" (IN LIST (Type), OUT RECORDS tt_records)
   LANGUAGE SQLSCRIPT
    SQL SECURITY INVOKER 
READS SQL DATA AS
    BEGIN
    RECORDS = select * from TABLE where ids in :LIST
    END;
```

How can I provide such a list to the proceudre?

Comment: yeah, its not, i removed the tag, its the Syntax for SAP HANA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Handing over lists of parameters to SQLScript is a bit tricky as there is no straight-forward native construct for that.

One way to do it is to use the `APPLY_FILTER` function and to "smuggle" the list as a string parameter.

In my example I read from a table `CUSERS` and I create a filter condition for `APPLY_FILTER` that filters column `USER_ID` via an `IN ( )` clause.

Removing the single quotes (`' '`) from the list is to avoid implicit type conversion when executing the query. Leaving the single quotes in place would make the `IN ()` clause make look like this:
`IN ( '<1st value>', '<2nd value>', '<3rd value>', ...)`
instead of
`IN (<1st value>, <2nd value>, <3rd value>, ...)`.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE  "GET_RECORDS" (IN id_list VARCHAR(4000)
                                , OUT RECORDS tt_cusers)
LANGUAGE SQLSCRIPT
SQL SECURITY INVOKER 
    READS SQL DATA AS
BEGIN
declare _filter VARCHAR(4000);

    _users = select * from cusers;

    -- APPLY_FILTER expects a proper WHERE condition, so adding the column to filter
    -- and the IN () expression is necessary.
    -- 
    -- the the id_list comes in with single quotes, let's remove those

    _filter = 'USER_ID in (' || replace (:id_list, '''', '') ||')';
    RECORDS = APPLY_FILTER(:_users, :_filter);    
end;    

call get_records (?, ?)

-- this 'list' is to be used as a single parameter value
-- '131072', '161223', '131074'
```

A slightly more comfortable approach for getting the data out from SAP HANA into R can be using a **table typed user-defined function** (UDF) instead. The main difference here is that the calling statement is a simple `SELECT` and the result is simply the resultset of this `SELECT`.

```
CREATE function  "FGET_RECORDS" (IN id_list VARCHAR(4000))
returns  tt_cusers
LANGUAGE SQLSCRIPT
SQL SECURITY INVOKER 
    READS SQL DATA AS
BEGIN
declare _filter VARCHAR(4000);

    _users = select * from cusers;

    -- APPLY_FILTER expects a proper WHERE condition, so adding the column to filter
    -- and the IN () expression is necessary.
    -- 
    -- the the id_list comes in with single quotes, let's remove those

    _filter = 'USER_ID in (' || replace (:id_list, '''', '') ||')';
    _result = APPLY_FILTER(:_users, :_filter);    
    RETURN :_result;
end;    


select * from fget_records (? );
```

In `R` (or in any other client) make sure to use bind variables when using this construct. Otherwise handling the different string quote-mechanisms can become cumbersome.

See the documentation on `APPLY_FILTER` [here](https://help.sap.com/viewer/de2486ee947e43e684d39702027f8a94/2.0.02/en-US/a09d584807f84477a64d7625ca45b089.html?q=APPLY_FILTER).

Comment: wouldn't this approach open holes for seq injections? you basically passing into a string and string can be of anything.. some sanitation needs to be done then @Lars

Comment: `APPLY_FILTER` prevents sql injections - see the linked documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Use a User Defined Data Type.

First Create A User Defined Data Type

Database Node > Programmability > Types > User-Defined Table Types

Script :

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.MyTableType AS TABLE 
(
    ID INT
)
```

Create a Parameter in your procedure with the above type

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_InsertMessages 
(
    @MyParameter MyTableType READONLY
)
AS
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO MyTable
    (
       id
    )
    SELECT 
       id
       FROM @MyParameter 

END
```

Comment: That means, does it consider the list as a column ?

Comment: Yes, it will be a column in the Table

Comment: Are you sure that is valid syntax for SAP HANA?

Comment: Not exactly, LIST needs a type, which I want to find out.

Comment: @JayasuryaSatheesh then i have to create a table ín R. I Need a way to take the list the way it is. I have no write previlaiges to write a new table.

Comment: @Sai this is for MS SQL. I added it as per your Tag for SQL Server

Comment: The idea works irrespective of the platform, I cannot write a table.